[Apache/Nginx]Can't remove ModSecurity rule for certain location
I am running a nextcloud instance on my apache webserver, but i can't download files like .gitignore, .env, etc.
This happens because of rule 210492 from comodo, which i have installed.
I can remove the rule by adding SecRuleRemoveById 210492 to the conf.
That works, but i would rather not remove the rule for the whole domain, hence i tried
<Location "/remote.php/dav">
    <IfModule mod_security2.c>
        SecRuleRemoveById 210492
    </IfModule>
</Location>

(/remote.php/dav is the entrypoint for a nextcloud client )
But it doesn't work, the rule is still active (based on the modsec_audit.log and a 403 in the browser). I can clearly see, that it matches the Location if i redirect instead of removing the rule.
I also tried this, but it has the same result.
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /remote.php/dav/""id:299999,log,ctl:ruleRemoveById=210492"

I can see that the url matches the rule based on the logs, but it doesn't remove the rule.
I am not sure what extra information i can provide. I use Plesk, so the different conf files are pretty spread out and probably not relevant.
Edit: SecRuleEngine Off in place it doesn't work either
<Location "/remote.php/dav">
    <IfModule mod_security2.c>
        SecRuleEngine Off
    </IfModule>
</Location>

Edit same problem with Nginx

"" should not be used, as what you want is actually trigger this rule or detect if there is a misconfiguration (if mod_security2 module is not installed).

with current setting, apache silently ignore the instructions within that IfModule block if apache is not able to load that module.
